# Taylor series of $e^{-x}$

Tags: calculus, discrete-mathematics

I am a little bit confused and this could be a stupid question.

The Taylor series of $e^x$ is $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n!}$.

Based on this, is it true that the Taylor expansion of $e^{-x}$ is $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^nx^n}{n!}$?

What's more, since $e^{-x}$ is the multiplicative inverse of $e^x$, is it also true that the Taylor expansion of $e^{-x}$ is just the sum $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{n!}{x^n}$?

Comment: That's basically like saying that $\dfrac1{a+b+c}=\dfrac1a+\dfrac1b+\dfrac1c$.

Answer (score 3):

The statement that $\displaystyle \text{“}e^x = \text{some expression involving } x \text{''}$ is supposed to be true no matter what number $x$ is.  Thus $\displaystyle e^{2\Omega+9} = \text{that same expression with “}2\Omega+9 \text{'' wherever “} x \text{'' appeared}$.

So $e^{-x}= \text{that same expression with } {-x} \text{ wherever } x \text{ appeared}$.

Thus you just need to put $\dfrac{(-x)^n}{n!}$ where $\dfrac{x^n}{n!}$ was.

Comment: And that's equal to the first thing OP had.

Answer (score 3):

Your first assertion is absolutely right.

Your second is wrong, because the reciprocal of a sum of a series is not in general equal to the sum of the reciprocals of each term in the series.